# Stop an action until all gameobjects have stopped colliding with barrier

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

So far in my code there is a collision detection method that sences when a certain sprite has hit a barrier, and there is also an action sequence I have implemented. In the action sequence I want there to be a wait period where the action stops until a certain amount of sprites have hit the ground (barrier). I've so far got the rotation and cubes falling and the main cube sprite, but the problem I'm trying to solve is getting the cube to stop rotating until all the cubes has hit the barrier. Basically stopping an action until a certain amount of projectile objects has collided with something, then continuing the action. Also the spawning of the cubes is part of the action sequence, so idk what to do without creating clutter in my code.

**Please find the below code for reference.**

```
class GameScene:SKScene {
    var wait:NSTimeInterval = 0
    var blocks = 0
    var cube = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cube")
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == barrierCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == objectCategory {
        secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()
        counterTest++
        print("hello")
    }
    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == blockCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == barrierCategory) {
         blocks++
    }

}
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        NSLog("Start") //Using NSLog just to print the current time
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(interval!), target: self, selector: Selector("spawnBlocks"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        cube.runAction(recursive())
    }

  }
    func recursive(){
        let recursive = SKAction.sequence([


            //SHOULD SPAWN ABOUT 10 BLOCKS
            SKAction.spawnBlocks,

            //WAIT UNTIL THE COLLISION HAS DETECTED 10 BLOCKS HIT THE BARRIER
            SKAction.waitForDuration(waitTime),

            //CONTINUE THE ROTATION OF THE CUBE SPRITE
            SKAction.rotate,

            SKAction.runBlock({[unowned self] in NSLog("Block executed"); self.recursive()})
            ])
        runAction(recursive, withKey: "aKey")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your action to be recursive.  this makes the logic hard to flow and is unnecessary.

If your cube has a continuous and autonomous behaviour, it should manage it itself in a subclass of SKSprite.

I would suggest you create a rotating action and run it "forever" on your cube.  Use removeActionWithName when you want it to stop.  Add it again when you want the rotation to resume.  This will enable you to implement an easy to use "startRotating" / "stopRotating" pair of functions that you can call whenever appropriate.

Same thing with the cube's continuous behaviour, place it in a runBlock action that repeats forever and start/stop other actions when conditions are met.

This will keep all the cube's behaviour within its own class (preferably in a separate file) and avoid you SKView from becoming a big unmanageable blob of code.